# I am a native speaker but have not learned grammar well, can I answer questions without grammar specifecs?

Tags: discussion, answers

I am a native English native, but I don't know technical grammar answers. and I often answer questions knowing they are correct *because I've listened to very good English all my life*, but not-Knowing *why*. (because of my lack of knowledge in grammar).

So my question is;

Is it OK to answer questions without giving any *why* or a technical grammar reasons?

Comment: Just to be clear, by "native speaker" do you mean that English is the primary language you have used since birth? I only ask because *native* is used loosely at times. Also what grammar level you are asking about is important, as it can range from grade school to university level grammar.

Comment: Most of the questions on ELL don't look for grammatical analyses, but rather "which sentence sounds better" or "which word should I choose", in which native speaker intuition is very helpful. See also [Native speaker answering questions](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1336/native-speaker-answering-questions?rq=1). I think your intuition is valuable in many of our questions.

Comment: Hi Sam - I would encourage you to not shy away from the grammatical questions but to research your answer. As native speakers, we have a huge advantage when it comes to searching for why something is correct. I've learned a lot about English by answering questions here. That said, there are some glaring errors in your question that concern me. I don't understand what you mean by "I've listened very good English all my life". That doesn't sound like something a native speaker would write. You don't have to be a native speaker to answer  http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/2655/

Comment: Also, there are some helpful people in [chat]. Some of the regular and semi-regular visitors are linguists.

Comment: @ColleenV, I meant "I've listened **to** very good English all my life". meaning that almost everyone I speak to is a native speaker = they have good grammar. also thank you your comment was helpful

Comment: Also thank you @IͶΔ for your comment.